# Why is the recap sequence of a TV series sometimes slightly different from the original material?

Tags: production

I have noticed that the recap sequence (*"Previously..."*) is sometimes different in subtle ways. The actors use slightly different words. It's almost the same material overall.

It's like the recap sequence is being patched together from takes that weren't used.

From what I recall, I have primarily seen this in *Star Trek*.

Why does this happen?

Comment: "often"? Please do not use qualifications like that unless you have the numbers to back them up.

Comment: @BCdotWEB you are correct. I have edited the question.

Comment: Speculation - because the recap is not cut by the same people who edited the show. They were handed a bunch of relevant footage, without the final show yet being complete. I've seen recaps that were in stereo, then jumped to 5.1 as the show proper starts. I would guess these were cut by the network, not the show itself.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example here from where you recorded an episode and the recap and compared them directly? Without one, it's entirely possible that you are just misremembering the original content.

Comment: @ruffdove Unfortunately, I don't have anything handy and it's like finding a needle in a haystack. I will post here if I find something again.

Comment: One example I can think of is in the BBC TV Series "Blakes' 7". One of the major characters, Avon, doesn't appear in the first episode - but does in the recap at the start of the 2nd.

Comment: @Tetsujin One example I'm aware of is the reboot of Battlestar Galactica. I've watched through the series three times and there are a number of scenes that appeared in a recap but weren't anywhere to be seen in the actual episodes. I suspect it's because they decided to explore a thread in a plot that needed a bit of background but the original scenes had been cut at the time.

Comment: The purpose of a "previously" sequence isn't to exactly reproduce the previous episode, but to recap the plot as quickly as possible. It's possible they deliberately used a different take that communicates the information better (e.g. slightly different words; or the speech was clearer for that line in that take, but another take was preferred overall). Or, as others have said, they could have had access to a different cut of the earlier episode for a multitude of reasons (e.g. earlier rough cut; not knowing which take was used; mistakenly given the wrong tape...). Too vague to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this many times, it's common, for at least 2 reasons: to affect how the viewer will feel following the clips, when going into the episode (e.g. more scared than the previous episode may have left them). Most other times it's to get across plot points without taking the time the original plot took to play out. And they're similar enough to scenes that were included in the original, so they're not too jarring, and can catch people up quicker than an actual clip would have.